# SVG clip-path uses expected coordinates in Firefox, but incorrectly offset in Chrome

Tags: svg, clip-path

Here's a simple SVG with an outlined rectangle with a clip path:

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="-40" y="-40" width="80" height="80" clip-path="path(&quot;M -10 -10 l 20 0 l 0 20 l -20 0 z&quot;)" fill="lightblue" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6aLnuc1h/1/

Important: note that the SVG is centered on 0, 0 (rather than having 0, 0 be in the top left) due to the `viewBox`. Thus, the `rect`'s top left corner is given as -40, -40.

Without the clip path, the SVG looks like this:

[image]

The clip path draws a 20x20 square, starting at -10, -10. In Firefox, this works as you'd expect, and it clips out a small square in the middle of the `rect`:

[image]

In Chrome, it seems to still be using the top left as the origin for the clip (instead of the adjusted coordinates per `viewBox`), and it ends up clipping a square in the top left corner of the `rect` instead:

[image]

I wasn't able to find any documentation on this behavior or anything stating which behavior is correct/expected. It certainly *seems* like Firefox is doing it properly. I'm not sure what Chrome is doing here -- maybe it's assuming clip paths' origins are the top left of the element they clip?

How can I define the clip path such that the browsers agree? I'm not married to one or the other choice, but I'm trying to avoid inspecting the user agent to decide how to define the clip path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure who's right, according to [the specs](https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking/#the-clip-path), the `<basic-shape>`'s *reference box* is supposed to default to `border-box`, while it seems it defaults to `view-box` in Firefox, I'm not 100% clear what should that `border-box` actually map to here.

But anyway, stable Chrome still doesn't support setting a reference box in `clip-path: <basic-shape> <geometry-box>`, so you can't have Firefox's behavior there, while in Canary with the chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag on, you can, even though they still default to the owner SVG's position:

```css
/* Using CSS as it's clearer */
rect {
  /* In Chrome Canary this will produce the same result as in Firefox */
  clip-path: path("M -10 -10 l 20 0 l 0 20 l -20 0 z") view-box;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <rect x="-40" y="-40" width="80" height="80" fill="lightblue" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This sounds promising, but I don't see the fixed behavior in Canary (118.0.5976.0 arm64). It seems to ignore the clip path entirely if I specify `view-box`. Also, the spec text is a bit confusing: the default is `border-box`, but it doesn't list `border-box` as a valid option. Maybe that's why you say Firefox can't mimic Chrome? Maybe it has no way to specify `border-box`. [Edit: nevermind, I missed `<shape-box>`.]

Comment: @skelley oh right, I have chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features on on my Canary, that's needed. And indeed the specs are confusing. It seems that `border-box` would have different meanings based on where it's used for SVGs...

Comment: Ah yup, that does it, thanks for adding that in there.